# I want to adjust blockquote tag in between p tag without collision of text

Tags: html, css

I want to put blockquote tag in between p tag but both tag should have their own space and dont want to collide the text of both tags.

https://ibb.co/jpGSHw

this is link of image of which result i want.

i am trying this

```
<p class="sm half">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <blockquote class="pull-right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <footer><cite class="author"> The Great  "Amit Chauhan" <cite></footer>
      </blockquote>
    </p>
```

and my css is

```
.half {
       width: 60%;
       display: inline-block;
      }
 blockquote{
      width: 40%;
      display: inline-block;
      }
```

Comment: thanks in advance any kind of help is accepted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.half {
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

blockquote {
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sm half">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
  <div>
  <blockquote>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <footer>
      <cite class="author"> The Great  "Amit Chauhan</cite>
    </footer>
  </blockquote>
  </div>
  sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: its almost right but in your code paragraph text is breaking , i don't want to break the paragraph text like in the image . Thank you so much for your time and appreciate your effort :)

Comment: There, you have to use a div or a container instead of p tag that's why it was breaking. Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular `div`, containing the `blockquote`. Then just float your quote. You could also use two seperate paragraphs, with the blockquote inbetween them.

```css
.paragraph  {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

blockquote {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 240px;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: grey;
}

.author { 
  float: right;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <blockquote>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <footer><cite class="author"> The Great  "Amit Chauhan" </cite></footer>
  </blockquote>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: tq you so for your answer